# Right way to refresh the token

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

There is a function `getUser` in `RequestManager class` that called in my `VC`.

```
func getUser(onCompletion: @escaping (_ result: User?, error: String?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.getUser).responseJSON { (response) in
        // here is the work with response
    }
}
```

If this request returns `403` it means `access_token` is expired. I need to refresh token and repeat the request from my `VC`.

Now the question.

How to refresh token and repeat the request in the right way?

To handle the error and refresh token in `MyViewController` or `getUser` method is not good idea because I have a lot of `VCs` and `request methods`.

I need something like: `VC` calls the method and gets the `User` even if token is expired and `refreshToken` must **not** be in all request methods.

**EDIT**

`refreshToken` method

```
func refreshToken(onCompletion: @escaping (_ result: Bool?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.refreshToken).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            guard let data = response.data else { return onCompletion(false) }
            let token = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: data)
            token?.setToken()
            onCompletion(true)
        } else {
            onCompletion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for refresh-token API call as well

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal is it necessary? have added

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To solve this, I created a class from which we will call every API, say `BaseService.swift`.

**BaseService.swift :**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import iComponents

struct AlamofireRequestModal {
    var method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod
    var path: String
    var parameters: [String: AnyObject]?
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding
    var headers: [String: String]?

    init() {
        method = .get
        path = ""
        parameters = nil
        encoding = JSONEncoding() as ParameterEncoding
        headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                   "Cache-Control": "no-cache"]
    }
}

class BaseService: NSObject {

    func callWebServiceAlamofire(_ alamoReq: AlamofireRequestModal, success: @escaping ((_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: NSError?) -> Void)) {

        // Create alamofire request
        // "alamoReq" is overridden in services, which will create a request here
        let req = Alamofire.request(alamoReq.path, method: alamoReq.method, parameters: alamoReq.parameters, encoding: alamoReq.encoding, headers: alamoReq.headers)

        // Call response handler method of alamofire
        req.validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                if statusCode == 200 {
                    Logs.DLog(object: "\n Success: \(response)")
                    success(data as AnyObject?)

                } else if statusCode == 403 {
                    // Access token expire
                    self.requestForGetNewAccessToken(alaomReq: alamoReq, success: success, failure: failure)

                } else {
                    let errorDict: [String: Any] = ((data as? NSDictionary)! as? [String: Any])!
                    Logs.DLog(object: "\n \(errorDict)")
                    failure(errorTemp as NSError?)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                Logs.DLog(object: "\n Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                failure(error as NSError?)
            }
        })
    }

}

extension BaseService {

    func getAccessToken() -> String {
        if let accessToken =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefault.userAccessToken) as? String {
            return "Bearer " + accessToken
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    // MARK: - API CALL
    func requestForGetNewAccessToken(alaomReq: AlamofireRequestModal, success: @escaping ((_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: NSError?) -> Void) ) {

        UserModal().getAccessToken(success: { (responseObj) in
            if let accessToken = responseObj?.value(forKey: "accessToken") {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: UserDefault.userAccessToken)
            }

            // override existing alaomReq (updating token in header)
            var request: AlamofireRequestModal = alaomReq
            request.headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                               "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                               "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                               "X-Authorization": self.getAccessToken()]

            self.callWebServiceAlamofire(request, success: success, failure: failure)

        }, failure: { (_) in
            self.requestForGetNewAccessToken(alaomReq: alaomReq, success: success, failure: failure)
        })
    }

}
```

For calling the API from this call, we need to create a object of `AlamofireRequestModal` and override it with necessary parameter.

For example I created a file `APIService.swift` in which we have a method for `getUserProfileData`.

**APIService.swift :**

```
import Foundation

let GET_USER_PROFILE_METHOD = "user/profile"

struct BaseURL {
    // Local Server
    static let urlString: String = "http://192.168.10.236: 8084/"
    // QAT Server
    // static let urlString: String = "http://192.171.286.74: 8080/"

    static let staging: String = BaseURL.urlString + "api/v1/"
}

class APIService: BaseService {

    func getUserProfile(success: @escaping ((_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: NSError?) -> Void)) {

        var request: AlamofireRequestModal = AlamofireRequestModal()
        request.method = .get
        request.path = BaseURL.staging + GET_USER_PROFILE_METHOD
        request.headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                           "X-Authorization": getAccessToken()]

        self.callWebServiceAlamofire(request, success: success, failure: failure)
    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

In code block:

```
else if statusCode == 403 {
    // Access token expire
    self.requestForGetNewAccessToken(alaomReq: alamoReq, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

I call getNewAccessToken API (say refresh-token, in your case), with the request( it could be any request based from APIService.swift).

When we get new token I save it user-defaults then I will update the request( the one I am getting as a parameter in refresh-token API call), and will pass the success and failure block as it is.

Comment: Wonderful brother. The exact thing which I want. Thank you :-)

Comment: what will do in case we have parallel api calles

Comment: @PramodShukla I had same question. I already tried but it failed in parallel api calls. Any idea / suggestion to overcome this. i already made my refresh token method synchronous and used semaphore but still it not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic refresher class:

```
protocol IRefresher {
    associatedtype RefreshTarget: IRefreshing

    var target: RefreshTarget? { get }

    func launch(repeats: Bool, timeInterval: TimeInterval)
    func invalidate()
}

class Refresher<T: IRefreshing>: IRefresher {

    internal weak var target: T?
    private var timer: Timer?

    init(target: T?) {
        self.target = target
    }

    public func launch(repeats: Bool, timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: repeats) { [weak self] (timer) in
            self?.target?.refresh()
        }
    }

    public func invalidate() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

And the refresh target protocol:

```
protocol IRefreshing: class {
    func refresh()
}
```

Define new typealias:

```
typealias RequestManagerRefresher = Refresher<RequestManager>
```

Now create refresher and store it:

```
class RequestManager {
    let refresher: RequestManagerRefresher

    init() {
        refresher = Refresher(target: self)
        refresher?.launch(repeats: true, timeInterval: 15*60)
    }
}
```

And expand RequestManager:

```
extension RequestManager: IRefreshing {
    func refresh() {
        updateToken()
    }
}
```

Every 15 minutes your RequestManager's token will be updated

---

### UPDATE

Of course, you also can change the update time. Create a static var that storing update time you need. For example inside the RequestManager:

```
class RequestManager {
    static var updateInterval: TimeInterval = 0

    let refresher: RequestManagerRefresher

    init() {
        refresher = Refresher(target: self)
        refresher?.launch(repeats: true, timeInterval: updateInterval)
    }
}
```

So now you can ask the token provider server for token update interval and set this value to updateInterval static var:

```
backendTokenUpdateIntervalRequest() { interval in
    RequestManager.updateInterval = interval
}
```

Comment: I didn’t need to update my token every 15 min, but only when it was expired @vboyko

Comment: @aaisataev updated, you should ask your backend server for expiration interval value

Comment: @vboyko Could you please explain where is this coming from ""authenticationService.refresher = Refresher(target: self)"". I'm having a hard time to figure this out.

Comment: @fazeelahamed fixed. This line creates Refresher with self as a target and set it to property.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily Refresh token and retry your previous API call using **Alamofire
RequestInterceptor**

**NetworkManager.Swift**:-

```
import Alamofire
    class NetworkManager {
        static let shared: NetworkManager = {
            return NetworkManager()
        }()
        typealias completionHandler = ((Result<Data, CustomError>) -> Void)
        var request: Alamofire.Request?
        let retryLimit = 3
        
        func request(_ url: String, method: HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                     encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.queryString, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
                     interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
            AF.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers, interceptor: interceptor ?? self).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
                if let data = response.data {
                    completion(.success(data))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure())
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

**RequestInterceptor.swift** :-

```
    import Alamofire
extension NetworkManager: RequestInterceptor {
    
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        var request = urlRequest
        guard let token = UserDefaultsManager.shared.getToken() else {
            completion(.success(urlRequest))
            return
        }
        let bearerToken = "Bearer \(token)"
        request.setValue(bearerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        print("\nadapted; token added to the header field is: \(bearerToken)\n")
        completion(.success(request))
    }
    
    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error,
               completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
         guard let statusCode = request.response?.statusCode else {
    completion(.doNotRetry)
    return
}

guard request.retryCount < retryLimit else {
    completion(.doNotRetry)
    return
}
print("retry statusCode....\(statusCode)")
switch statusCode {
case 200...299:
    completion(.doNotRetry)
case 401:
    refreshToken { isSuccess in isSuccess ? completion(.retry) : completion(.doNotRetry) }
    break
default:
    completion(.retry)
} 
    }
    
    func refreshToken(completion: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> Void) {
                let params = [
"refresh_token": Helpers.getStringValueForKey(Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN)
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data, let token = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                as? [String: Any])?["access_token"] as? String {
                UserDefaultsManager.shared.setToken(token: token)
                print("\nRefresh token completed successfully. New token is: \(token)\n")
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

> Alamofire v5 has a property named RequestInterceptor.
> RequestInterceptor has two method, one is Adapt which assign
> access_token to any Network call header, second one is Retry method.
> In Retry method we can check response status code and call
> refresh_token block to get new token and retry previous API again.