# Refresh Token with Alamofire retry count and retry request swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I am using `Alamofire` to integrate API calls, handling error code and specially status code error like `401` and `403`. I have also created the `getRefreshToken()` function, if error comes it will refresh the token.

Problem I am facing about `Alamofire.retryCount` and repeat the request in the right way? I have seen different references but I cannot figure out How I integrate in my main method.

**Updated:** added `getRefreshToken()` code.

My Code:

```
@objc private func getDataFromWeb(params:NSMutableDictionary,
                                callback:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ result:Any?)->(Bool)) -> Void {
        var method = HTTPMethod.get
        var encoding = URLEncoding.default as ParameterEncoding
        if(params["Method"] as! String == "POST"){
            method = HTTPMethod.post
            encoding = Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default
        }       
        
        Alamofire.request(url,
                          method:method,
                          parameters:pr,
                          encoding:encoding,
                          headers:[ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
            .downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            //progress closure
            })
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { response in
                 print(response.error?.localizedDescription)
                 var code = response.response?.statusCode
                
                if code == 401 || code == 403{
                    
                    self.getRefreshToken()    // calling refresh token method
                    
                    
                } else {
                if(callback(response.data?.count != 0, response.data)){
                    
                    }
                }
                
        }
        
    
    }
```

getRefreshToken Function:

```
func getRefreshToken() {
        
        DataProvider.main.serviceLogin(username:User, password:Pass, firmNo: FirmId , callback:{success, result in
                            do{
                                if(success){
                                    let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Login.self, from: result as! Data)
                                    if model.isSuccess == true {

                                        DataProvider.main.token = model.token
                                        

                                    }

                                    return true

                                    } else{

                                    return false
                                    }
                                
                            }catch let e {
                                    print(e)

                                    return false
                                }
            
        })
    }
```

References:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496713/retry-the-old-request-with-new-refresh-token-in-swift-alamofire

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287882/right-way-to-refresh-the-token
```

Comment: Where does the guy named 'getRefreshToken' come from and why are you calling it when the http status code is 401 or 403?

Comment: @ElTomato  its the function `self.getRefreshToken()`to get new refresh token. I haven't posted the code of that function.

Comment: @ElTomato I have added `getRefreshToken()` function code.